# Differential equations - approach for certain types of questions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

**Problem:**

> $$(\frac{dy}{dx})^2 - x\frac{dy}{dx} + y = 0$$

I attempted to solve the equation by assuming $\frac{dy}{dx}$ to be $t$. I then used the formula for general solutions of a quadratic equation to obtain the value of $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Would this be the correct way to solve such problems? (Considering the answer I got didn't match the given answer.)

Comment: I would say, it is a Clairaut's equation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rearranging gives
$$
y=-(\frac{dy}{dx})^2+x\frac{dy}{dx}.
$$ 
Differentiating using the product and chain rule gives
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=x\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{dy}{dx}-2\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}.
$$
Rearranging gives 
$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}(x-\frac{dy}{dx})=0.
$$
One of these terms must be zero. Set both of these equal to zero and solve. Can you finish from here?

Comment: Ahhaaa..... See that makes much more sense. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. You're welcome.